# Core Data NSManagedObject in Xcode 9 beta

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, xcode9-beta

NSManagedObject Subclass is absent form Xcode 9 project files templates. Data Model and Mapping model project file templates are present. What we should be using instead of NSManagedObject Subclass while doing objective c programming using core data?

[image]

That project template of NSManagedObject is absent

Comment: Xcode 8 (tag) or 9 (title)?

Comment: Xcode 9 beta -title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should still use `NSManagedObject` subclasses.

The option you're looking for moved to the "Editor" menu (last year, I think-- it's not new). It's now called "Create NSManagedObject Subclass".

This is where you find it:

[image]

*However*, Since Xcode 8, class generation is automatic if you want it to be. Each entity now has a "Codegen" setting in the model editor that controls how this works. You can choose a couple of different automatic generation options, or you can turn off automatic code generation.

Comment: I have seen "Editor" in Xcode 9 .There is no option for "Create NSManagedObject Subclass".as you check this link https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=editor+menu+xcode+9&num=100&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOv5_F4YbVAhXoIcAKHbLGC00Q_AUICigB&biw=1024&bih=601#imgrc=qoFDxIE_Ba9s1M:

Comment: That link is meaningless. The items on the "Editor" menu change depending on what you're doing in Xcode. If you are editing a Core Data model, this option is available. Otherwise the menu contains other items appropriate to your current activity.

Comment: i have uploaded images." Create NSManagedObject Subclass" is absent

Comment: You didn't read my comment. The items on the menu change depending on what kind of document you are editing. The Core Data option is only present **when you are editing a Core Data model**. You screenshot shows that you are not doing that, therefore the option is not present. I'm honestly sorry that I tried to help you at this point.